# what happens if I leave out ensure_signed from extrinsic?

Tags: transactions, extrinsic, signed-extensions, origin

What are the attack vectors of leaving out `ensured_signed` in
one of my extrinsic?

It seems that SignedExtensions already checks if the transactions are signed. When I try to submit an unsigned transaction, it automatically fails.

It seems that this is a convention everyone follows when writing extrinsic, but I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `submit_unsigned`?

I think people could submit unsigned transactions on your chain without paying any fee.

Obviously, this will cause something like DDOS. Use a script to submit the unsigned transactions.

---

Why do we need unsigned?

1. Airdrop, like the Polkadot claim module. It's not a good idea to require a user to own some token first and then to claim the airdrop. So they set the claim extrinsic feeless.
2. For some public-welfare calls, like the sync finality proof in the cross-chain bridge pallet. It's a one-time verification/call, after the first successful call it will reject the others.
3. Something like @Oliver described.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with allowing unsigned extrinsics is that nobody pays for the consumed weight.
So you are basically doing work for free - normally undesirable.

The only use-case where it is a good idea are cleanup operations which remove storage items.
A smaller state means less PoV of storage READ/REMOVE operations and is therefore desirable.
One could say that storage cleanups have an amortized "negative" weight and should therefore be free.

Comment: It looks like if we are using a signed extension with the [check_non_zero_sender](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/system/src/extensions/check_non_zero_sender.rs signed-extension, why do we need to still ensured_signed in an extrinsics?

Comment: `check_non_zero_sender` just checks that nobody is using the `0x00000…` address. That is different from signed/unsigned. You want to use `ensured_signed` so that someone pays for the extrinsic. Otherwise your chain does work for free by accepting unsigned extrinsics.

Comment: Can I check ensured_signed in a SignedExtension? Is the following answer correct?
https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5588/how-can-i-check-origin-in-a-signedextension/5611#5611