# How can I check origin in a SignedExtension?

Tags: transactions, signed-extensions

How can I check the origin in a SignedExtension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check the 'who' parameter in the 'fn validate()' function.

An example from the chech_non_zero_sender extension: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/21d58f6f7b3ed2ea529f3c118b2e042b29551672/frame/system/src/extensions/check_non_zero_sender.rs#L85

Comment: are you saying that I should call ensure_signed(who) inside the signed-extension?

Comment: That will not work. `ensure_signed` is expecting an origin, however `who` is an `AccountId`.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but if what you want is to check if a transaction is signed or not before it is included in the block, what you can do is to use build your own `UncheckedExtrinsic`.

You could modify `check()` method to reject transactions filtering them with `Call`.